# Distance function Returning the wrong thing

Tags: javascript, distance

For a while now, I have been trying to code a function that can calculate the distance between 2 points. I used this site: http://www.mathwarehouse.com/calculators/distance-formula-calculator.php to find the formula, but it kept returning different numbers. To put this into perspective, the site said that the distance from (0,0) and (50,100) was 111.80339887498948, and my computer said it was 7.483314773547883. I'm pretty sure the site is correct, but I have tried many algorithms and can't get it to return the same thing as the site did. Here is my code:

```js
var distance = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var a = x2 - x1;
    a ^= 2;
    var b = y2 - y1;
    b ^= 2;
    var c = a + b;
    return Math.sqrt(c);
};
```

Can you tell me why this is saying the wrong thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is the [bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#(Bitwise_XOR)) operator in JavaScript, so `^= 2` isn't doing what you expect.

The [exponential operator (`**`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)) exists in ES2016, but unless you are using a transpiler it might not have the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Browser_compatibility) you are after.

A few alternatives:

Multiplication

```
var distance = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var dx = x2 - x1;
  var dy = y2 - y1;

  return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

Using [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

```
var distance = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var dx = x2 - x1;
  var dy = y2 - y1;

  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));
}
```

Using [exponential operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**))

```
var distance = function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {    
  return Math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Math.pow` to use exponents:

```js
function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var a = Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2);
    var b = Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2);
    return Math.sqrt(a + b);
};

console.log(distance(0,0,0,50))
```